# KineticJS: Clicks to background layers stop firing after draw

Tags: events, kineticjs

KineticJS seems to have an issue with handling clicks on background layers after redrawing the stage.

I have a jsfiddle with a minimal example of this problem. http://jsfiddle.net/Z2SJS/

On line 34 I have:

```
stage.draw()
```

If this is commented out, events fire as they should. When this is present, after dragging the click events to the background will stop firing.

I know that in this example I am not doing anything that would require me to redraw the stage, but in my project I am using the dragstart and dragmove events to manipulate objects on multiple layers, and I then lose reference to my background clicks.

Is there something I need to do to ensure that redrawing the stage does not cause my events to stop firing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `stage.draw()` use `foreground.draw()`

here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2SJS/1/)

Alternately: set `dragOnTop: false` inside the circle instantiation. [Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2SJS/2/)

Comment: Changing from redrawing the stage, to redrawing the individual affected layers worked for me.  Setting *dragOnTop: false* had no effect, I still could not call stage.draw(). Am I wrong in thinking that this is a bug?

Comment: Hmm... am not sure... I see that my fiddle still has foreground.draw() so it was not the dragOnTop which made the change. It seems that pressing back didn't help to set up new fiddle. Anyways! So that may not be a bug, but Eric (KineticJS creator) might be the best person to answer that

Comment: As an aside, for better performance it always good to redraw individual layers rather than the entire stage